# How to serve Craft with Caddy server

Tags: server, caddy

[Caddy](https://caddyserver.com) seems to be an easy to use alternative to established web servers. How does the `Caddyfile` look like for a Craft site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For local development the `Caddyfile` looks like this (assuming that php-fpm runs on port 9000, you may have to adapt `root` to point to your web root relative to the location of the `Caddyfile`):

```
localhost:2020 {
    root public_html
    fastcgi / 127.0.0.1:9000 php
    rewrite {
        r .*
        to {uri} {uri}/ /index.php?p={uri}&{query} /index.php?{query}
    }
}
```

**Edit:** For Caddy `>= 0.9.x` the `rewrite` has to be changed to this:

```
rewrite {
  to {path} {path}/ /index.php?p={path}&{query} /index.php?{query}
}
```

Comment: Have you noticed any issues with running tasks with Caddy server? I've noticed that even P&T's own PowerNap task example doesn't run properly on Caddy.